# Implementing ng-if with ng-repeat for selected option tag in HTML and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a dropdown, using select and option tags with AngularJS, referencing a model, like this.

```
<select id="edit-location" class="" ng-model="packageLoc">
    <option ng-repeat="x in loc" value="{{ x.locationId }}">{{ x.locationLoc }} - ({{ x.locationFloor }}{{ x.locationBuilding }})</option>
</select>
```

This dropdown lists about seven location IDs that the user can choose from.

However, I have another model that brings up a specific location ID from another entry; this location ID will definitely be one of the location IDs that show up in the dropdown above. Call this `packageSearch.locationId`. This is only going to be one number.

If this location ID matches one of the location IDs in the dropdown above, I want the `selected` keyword to show, making the dropdown above display the location ID from my second model.

I've tried to implement this with ng-if. But I'm unsuccessful. See below:

```
<select id="edit-location" class="" ng-model="packageLoc">
    <option ng-repeat="x in loc" value="{{ x.locationId }}" ng-if="{{ x.locationId === packageSearch.locationId" selected>{{ x.locationLoc }} - ({{ x.locationFloor }}{{ x.locationBuilding }})</option>
</select>
```

How would I be able to apply the `selected` keyword to one of the `<option>` elements with AngularJS if that element's value matches another model's data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected):

```
<select id="edit-location" class="" ng-model="packageLoc">
    <option ng-repeat="x in loc"
        value="{{ x.locationId }}"
        ng-selected="x.locationId === packageSearch.locationId">
            {{ x.locationLoc }} - ({{ x.locationFloor }}{{ x.locationBuilding }})
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a selected attribute, I'd recommend you set the model (packageLoc) with the correct value when this condition is met.

Assuming that you've another select which sets packageSearch, you can do something like this:

```
<select id="search-location" ng-model="packageSearch" ng-change="setLocation()">
    <option ng-repeat="..."></option>
</select>
```

In the setLocation function in your controller you can write something like this:

```
packageLoc = packageSearch; (or whatever you'd like to do here)
```

Comment: Sure. Can you give me an example?